# Remove attribute value before #

Tags: xml, xslt

I have many xml files that have an element like this:

```
<link refID="hdb-tbl-map.dita#topic_x33_ttl_4q">
```

or

```
<link refID="#topic_xwd_fbt_4q" format="dita">
```

I want to only have the value after # to be present in the attribute value.

So the resulting xml will have the elements like this without the format attribute.

```
<link refID="topic_x33_ttl_4q">
```

and

```
<link refID="topic_xwd_fbt_4q">
```

I need to change only this element and nothing else in the xml.

Answer (score 1):

Therefore you are asking for a XSLT solution (as tagged), try this one:

**XSLT 1.0 + 2.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="link/@refID">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(.,'#')"/>
        </xsl:attribute>       
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="link/@format"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result for example**

```
<link refID="topic_x33_ttl_41"/>
```

**Explanation**

First template matches on attribute `@refID` of element `link`. Recreates the attribute with same name `{name()}`.

Second template matches attribute `@format` of element `link` and does nothing, so it will be removed.

Last template is a *identity copy template*. Copy from source to target 1:1.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse :

```
Ctrl + H -> File search` -> Containing text : #   File name patterns : *.xml -> Replace
```

In the new windows on input 'with' put ""

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: (I'm assuming you are in a java surrounding and parsing these xml-strings?)

```
str = str.replaceAll("\".*#(.*)\"", "$1");
```

What it does?

Searching the character ", then some chars, then #, then get the next part until another " is given.